# Tap event for inline image of RichEditBox uwp app

Tags: uwp, rtf, inline-images, richeditbox

I am working on a UWP app in which am working RichEditBox with inline images.
Here I want do some operations based on which image the user tapped. 
I am not able to find any events to handle when the inline image is tapped. 
Tapped and PointerPressed events not triggering for RichEditBox.
Clearly what i want is a event in which i can get which inline image is clicked or tapped.

I am getting the image file from image library by file picker as StorageFile.

Here is the code through which I insert image to RichEditBox

```
 using (var imageStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);

                richEditBox.Document.Selection.InsertImage((int)bitmapImage.PixelWidth, (int)bitmapImage.PixelHeight, 0, Windows.UI.Text.VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, "ImageName", imageStream);
                imagePosition.Add(imageFilesList[0]);
            };
```

Can anyone help me to short this out?

Thank you.
Noorul.

Comment: Can you include your code to insert Image in RichEditBox?

Comment: Hi Vijay, thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with code, please check it.